# Debug Baidu Apollo in CLion 2022 With Bazel Plugin

Tags: bazel, clion

[Baidu Apollo](https://github.com/ApolloAuto/apollo) is a open source self-driving car platform written of course in C++ and built with Bazel.

Apollo is a component based system, meaning that each module is a shared library component that is loaded using a directed acyclic graph.

For example, the camera driver is loaded by its `.dag` [file](https://github.com/ApolloAuto/apollo/blob/master/modules/drivers/camera/dag/camera.dag), like so

```
bazel-bin/cyber/mainboard -d <path-to-dag-file>
```

I would like to bebug this camera driver through the Clion bazel plugin by creating a bazel build target for the `mainboard`.  But since the camera driver is not a dependency of the mainboard, bazel removes it from the running cache, and mainboard does not find the `so` to load.

Comment: Make the so file a data dependency

Comment: @Vertexwahn I guess that would work for debug, but I would have to change that each time I want to debug a different component.